# Docker on VM stoped working fine after shutdown

Tags: docker, daemon, sandbox

I'm working on a virtual machine with sandbox hdp ambari, nifi.... 
I needed more space so i did a resize on mymachine.vdi but to see that resize and asign more space to the partition, i have to shut down the machine.

When i start it again, "docker start sandbox-proxy" give the error specified down.

I'm trying to start sandbox-hdp , sandbox-proxy and mysql.
Start sandbox-hdp works fine but when i try to start sandbox-proxy, docker gives me this error:

```
sudo docker start sandbox-proxy
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/home/ubuntu/Descargas/scripts/assets/nginx.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebbbe053a9670b801ef0119f4502630a618268fe87c586d2cd2cb8423142d737/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ebbbe053a9670b801ef0119f4502630a618268fe87c586d2cd2cb8423142d737/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Error: failed to start containers: sandbox-proxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error it seems you're trying to mount a directory on a file.

Please go through [this](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/297#issuecomment-369198124).

You need to:

- Check if file `/home/ubuntu/Descargas/scripts/assets/nginx.conf` exists on the daemon host.
- if it didn't exist, docker now created a directory at the path above; remove that directory and replace it with the file you're trying to mount
- You can also use the `--mount` flag instead of `-v` / `--volume`: the `--mount` flag will not automatically create a directory if the host-path is missing, but instead produce an error, so that you're aware the path (file/directory) on the host is missing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it still dindt help.